# AWS EC2 Launchtemplate vs Launchconfiguration

Tags: amazon-ec2

I’m wondering when one should use which one.

It seems Launchtemplates are more advanced because they allow for versioning but on the other side you cannot set EBS settings etc.

Is Launchtemplate a better version of Launchconfiguration or do they serve different purposes so meaning if you don’t want versioning stick with Launchconfigs with no harm for the future.

Thanks A

Comment: There is also this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-purchase-options.html that requires launch templates... Volume settings seems to be included in Launch Templates

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8e7txs/autoscaling_launch_configuration_versus_launch/dxznx2o/):

> Launch templates allow control of the T2 unlimited (credits) feature, at least that is the one feature I needed, so had to use launch templates.
>
> However, it seems that a launch template specifies exactly one subnet, rather than a list (like launch configurations).
>
> They're quite difference and CloudFormation and it has sucked up several hours of trial and error on my part to get them working.

From my experience, you cannot specify a subnet in either a launch configuration or launch template so I'm not sure where that came from. It appears to me that a launch template is the new version of a launch configuration but I have not seen anywhere that AWS is saying they'll deprecate launch configurations.

I do remember when they brought in application load balancers, it took a while for them to announce deprecation of classic load balancers so my gut feel is that's what will happen here too. Note the [CloudFormation docs for Autoscaling Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) recommend using launch templates to get the latest features.

Personally, I'm still using launch configurations since it does not appear very hard to translate to launch templates if/when the time comes, [AWS will even do it for you](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/copy-launch-config.html).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the versioning features of the launch template "I didn't need to use this because I rely on git"

The use case I needed to use LT over LC is basically I needed to mix the instance types for kubernets nodes for the same autoscaling group.

Basically I need to have a minimum number of nodes running within EKS as worker nodes (3 nodes) so this was (either on-demand or reserved) in our case we used on-demant and for any extra workload we just fire spot instances with specificed bidding price ...etc.

That is one of use cases I am not sure if launch configuration would allow this but definitely LT allows mixed instances types within same LT